# How to run redis client with remote server?

Tags: redis-cluster, redis-cache

How to run redis client with remote url and how to get list of connections are stored in redis cache?

https://redis.io/commands/info

Answer (score 2):

1)You can download and install **redis** for **Unix**([here](https://redis.io/download)).

2) Go to command line and connect using below command:

```
   Command: redis-cli -h <HOST> -p <PORTNO>
   (You can additionaly use -a option if authentication is enabled.)
```

3) You would enter the redis-cli console and there you use the below commands

```
    Command: CLIENT LIST  (to display all client connected to redis with some additional info)
    Command: INFO CLIENTS (to display count of client connections to redis)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run redis client with remote url with following steps.

```
> 1. Install redis client
> 2. Open folder > C:\Program Files\Redis
> 3. Open CMD (ADMINISTRATOR)
> 4. Run Command > redis-cli.exe -h tickets-prod.6c2eqs.ng.0001.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379 These are
> child command to get result:
> > monitor
> > multi
> > exec
> > keys *
> > Get ClientListGB
> > help
> > help @list
> > quite
> > info
```

info command will give full detail of redis server.

Thanks